# Why is ViewModelScoped coroutine unusable after ViewModel onCleared() method called

Tags: android, dagger-2, kotlin-coroutines, android-viewmodel

I am sharing an ActivityScoped viewModel between multiple Fragments in my current Android application.

The viewModel employs Coroutine Scope `viewModelScope.launch{}`

My issue is the `.launch{}` only works until the owning `ViewModel` `onCleared()` method is called.

Is this how ViewModel scoped coroutines are supposed to work?

Is there an approach I can use to "Reset" the viewModelScope so that .launch{} works following the onCleared() method being called?

heres my code::

**Fragment**

```
RxSearchView.queryTextChangeEvents(search)
        .doOnSubscribe {
            compositeDisposable.add(it)
        }
        .throttleLast(300, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .debounce(300, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .map { event -> event.queryText().toString() }
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe { charactersResponse ->
            launch {
                viewModel.search(charactersResponse.trim())
            }
        }
```

.
.
.

```
override fun onDetach() {
    super.onDetach()
    viewModel.cancelSearch()
    compositeDisposable.clear()
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
suspend fun search(searchString: String) {
    cancelSearch()

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(searchString)) {
        return
    }

    job = viewModelScope.launch {
        repository.search(searchString)
    }
}

fun cancelSearch() {
    job?.cancelChildren()
}
```

.
.
.

```
override fun onCleared() {
    super.onCleared()
    repository.onCleared()
 }
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

If I amend my launch code to this

```
job = GlobalScope.launch {
    repository.search(searchString)
}
```

It solves my issue, however is this the only way to achieve my desired result?

I was under the impression `GlobalScope` was "Bad"

Comment: You should not have to create your own ViewModelStore. The Activity is already a ViewModelStoreOwner, which delegates `onCleared()` callback at the right time.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce you are correct (as always :)) anywho... I still have the issue that my ViewModel is only created once and following a cal to onCleared() my viewModelScoped cororoutine Launch stops executing. What are my options? Replace viewModelScope with GlobalScope or some how force a new instance of my viewModel to be created once onCleared() has been called

Comment: `GlobalScope` isn't a bad as it seems to be portrayed. Sometimes it is simply what you need, it just happens that most times it won't be what you should be using.

Comment: "is this the only way to achieve my desired result?" No it is not, you can also add your own scope to an object with sufficient lifetime. Maybe your repository, but it seems you kill your repository at the same time as your ViewModel since you forward the onCleared()?

Comment: `Is this how ViewModel scoped coroutines are supposed to work?` yes `Is there an approach I can use to "Reset" the viewModelScope so that .launch{} works following the onCleared() method being called?` no `It solves my issue, however is this the only way to achieve my desired result?` yes  `I was under the impression GlobalScope was "Bad"` no

Comment: "GlobalScope isn't a bad as it seems to be portrayed " Roman from Kotlin Coroutines team discourages use of GlobalScope which makes it pretty bad. Better to create your own scope: https://medium.com/@elizarov/the-reason-to-avoid-globalscope-835337445abc

Comment: @Enselic honestly, global scope is for running tasks... in the global scope. Things that don't need to be cancelled can (and should!) be executed in the global scope.

Comment: This doesn't make much sense to me. If the VM is created only once, and intended for reuse, of what use is having a way to scope coroutines to the lifecycle of the VM if it's only of value the first time the VM is used?

Comment: Nevermind; I was retaining ViewModels through @Singleton instance @Provider(s) in Dagger, so they were never being reinitialized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> repository.onCleared()
> ```

This method should not belong to the Repository.

In fact, the Repository should not be stateful.

If you check Google's samples, [the Repository creates a `LiveData` that contains a `Resource`](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/20bcd0a68976a6abb2bc127522b21745a6f4d16f/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/repository/RepoRepository.kt#L76-L94), and the reason why this is relevant is because [the actual data loading and caching mechanic is inside this resource, triggered by `LiveData.onActive`](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/20bcd0a68976a6abb2bc127522b21745a6f4d16f/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/repository/NetworkBoundResource.kt#L49) (in this sample, `MediatorLiveData.addSource`, but technically that's semantically the same thing).

> ```
>     .subscribe { charactersResponse ->
>         launch {
>             viewModel.search(charactersResponse.trim())
> ```

The Fragment shouldn't be launching coroutines. It should say something like

```
.subscribe {
    viewModel.updateSearchText(charactersResponse.trim())
}
```

and also

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyViewModel::class.java, factory)
    viewModel.searchResults.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { results ->
        searchAdapter.submitList(results)
    })
}
```

Then ViewModel would

```
class MyViewModel(
    private val repository: MyRepository
): ViewModel() {
    private val searchText = MutableLiveData<String>()

    fun updateSearchText(searchText: String) {
        this.searchText.value = searchText
    }

    val searchResults: LiveData<List<MyData>> = Transformations.switchMap(searchText) {
        repository.search(searchText)
    }
}
```

And that's all there should be in the ViewModel, so then the question of "who owns the coroutine scope"? That depends on when the task should be cancelled.

If "no longer observing" should cancel the task, then it should be `LiveData.onInactive()` to cancel the task.

If "no longer observing but not cleared" should retain the task, then ViewModel's onCleared should indeed govern a SupervisorJob inside the ViewModel that would be cancelled in `onCleared()`, and the `search` should be launched within that scope, which is probably only possible if you pass over the CoroutineScope to the `search` method.

```
suspend fun search(scope: CoroutineScope, searchText: String): LiveData<List<T>> =
    scope.launch {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { // or network or something
            val results = networkApi.fetchResults(searchText)
            withContext(Dispatchers.MAIN) {
                MutableLiveData<List<MyData>>().apply { // WARNING: this should probably be replaced with switchMap over the searchText
                    this.value = results
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Would this work? Not sure, I don't actually use coroutines, but I think it should. This example however doesn't handle the equivalent of `switchMap`-ing inside the LiveData, nor with coroutines.

Comment: EpicPandaForce thanks for taking the time to answer my question... "In fact, the Repository should not be stateful." my repository is not stateful, it has onCleared() method as it employs RxJava and I collect my disposables in  val compositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable() which I clear in onCleared()

Comment: What you're saying translates to that it's stateful.

Answer (score 11):

> following a cal to onCleared() my viewModelScoped cororoutine Launch stops executing

That's a feature, not a bug.

Once the `ViewModel` is cleared, you should not be doing *anything* in that `ViewModel` or whatever its `LifecycleOwner` was. All of that is now defunct and should no longer be used.

> however is this the only way to achieve my desired result?

The correct solution is to get rid of the code from the `ViewModel`. If you are expecting some background work to go past the lifetime of an activity or fragment, then that code does not belong in the activity/fragment or its associated viewmodels. It belongs in something that has a matching lifetime to the work that you are trying to do.